# Customize Additional setup page in Google Apps marketplace install wizard

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to publish my app to Google apps market place. For now, I published the app in a way that users who have the link can access it, When I try to install that app as an admin, it goes through this 3 step wizard

1. Asks permission
2. Asks whether to notify users or not
3. Shows an additional setup dialog with "Manage app" link and "Launch App" button

How can I customize the additional setup dialog so that instead of the default "Manage app", I can show my own setup url and link name?